# Document head squeezes

Tags: header-footer

I made a template for the lectures summary and it behaves a bit weird. Here's **MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\newcommand{\theme}{Theme}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % main language is the last one
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=25mm}
\geometry{bottom=25mm}
\geometry{left=20mm}
\geometry{right=20mm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1,2}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L,C]{}
\fancyhead[L]{\textbf{\theme}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{background}
\definecolor{shkolkovoBlue}{RGB}{2,140, 214}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle = {\theme},
    pdfauthor = me,
    urlbordercolor = 1 1 1
}
\newcommand{\makeCustomHeader}{
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \begin{flushleft}
        Some text \\
        Some text as well
    \end{flushleft}
    \begin{flushright}\vspace{-22mm}
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}
    \end{flushright}
    \begin{center}\vspace{-0.2cm}
        \textbf{ \large \theme}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}\vspace{-5mm}
        \rule{\linewidth}{0.1mm}
    \end{center}
    \begin{flushright}
        \color{shkolkovoBlue}{\underbar{Found a mistake?}}
    \end{flushright}
}
\backgroundsetup{
    scale=1.5,
    angle=0,
    opacity=0.2,
    contents={
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node at ([xshift=0pt, yshift=0pt] current page.center){\includegraphics{example-image}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
}}
\begin{document}
    \makeCustomHeader
    \lipsum[1-200]
\end{document}
```

But as I delete the text `\lipsum[1-200]`, my header widens a little bit (it is more noticeable if you place an image in the end of the first page)
So my question is - what might be the reason of this happening? Isn't spacing between elements strictly determined in a latex document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `lipsum` text (or any other text) added, LaTeX tries to fit an integral number of lines of text on the page. In order to fit that, it squeezes or stretches your header a bit. This can be done because the vertical space before and after `flushright`, `flushleft` and `center` have some flexibility in them.

You can prevent this squeezing by putting your header inside a `\parbox`.

```
\newcommand{\makeCustomHeader}{%
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{flushleft}
        Some text \\
        Some text as well
    \end{flushleft}
    \begin{flushright}\vspace{-22mm}
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}
    \end{flushright}
    \begin{center}\vspace{-0.2cm}
        \textbf{ \large \theme}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}\vspace{-5mm}
        \rule{\linewidth}{0.1mm}
    \end{center}
    \begin{flushright}
        \color{shkolkovoBlue}{\underbar{Found a mistake?}}
    \end{flushright}}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Have a great day:)